# I can't open the file in SQL Shell Permission Denied

Tags: postgresql

I have a 10gb postgresql file I am trying to open but it is not allowed.Pgadmin gives the output exit code as 1 and I can't get the data. When I do it in SQL Shell, it says it didn't allow it.When I put it in the general file areas, it still gives an error. I set the sharing options for everyone, it still didn't work.

Postgresql 9.6 and Pgadmin 4v4

Comment: Upgrade pgAdmin4.  v4 is quite old and had known bugs about showing proper error messages.  What is SQL Shell? Is that a proprietary MS product?  What is 'the general file  areas'?

Comment: I tried everything known, I asked because it was strange, I worked with the most up-to-date versions at first.